# Any open-source admin UI for quartz.NET

Tags: quartz.net

Is there available any open source admin interface to add/edit/delete jobs & triggers in QUARTZ.NET scheduler?

Comment: Please refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470599/combining-quartz-net-with-ui

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out this [blog](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/06/embeddable-quartznet-web-consoles.html).   He describes a few that worked for him and few others he investigated.

Once you know how to use the Quartz API (Example 12 - Client really helped me), it's not too difficult to extract whatever information you want.

Answer (score 14):

I recently published new alternative web UI for Quartz.NET. You can manage jobs, triggers, calendars and most of the API which IScheduler provide. It is pluggable into existing OWIN and ASP.NET Core application or it creates embedded web server on it own. You can put strongly typed values to JobDataMap or edit existing JobDataMap of job or trigger.

https://github.com/jlucansky/Quartzmin

Comment: do you have something similar for java , or how easy it will be to take just UI component and implement the backend ?

Answer (score 7):

Check out this other question: [Combining Quartz.Net with UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470599/combining-quartz-net-with-ui).

[QuartzNetWebConsole](https://github.com/mausch/QuartzNetWebConsole) and [crystal-quartz](https://github.com/guryanovev/CrystalQuartz) seem to be more active projects. Both are open-source and have [NuGet packages](http://nuget.org/packages?q=quartz.net) available.

Comment: CrystalQuartz for Quartz.Net 2: http://mattpenner.info/2011/10/10/crystalquartz-for-quartz-net-2/

Answer (score 5):

It seems that currently [CrystalQuartz](https://github.com/guryanovev/crystalquartz) is the best fitting solution here

Answer (score -4):

I combined this jquery plugin with my c# code and a hidden field. Worked well for me: I used this: http://shawnchin.github.com/jquery-cron/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and the link provided is dead.