# Combining Quartz.Net with UI

Tags: job-scheduling, quartz.net-2.0

I have been working on MVC3 project. I have just created Sample email sending job with Quartz.Net in my application. This time, I need to build a job scheduling system in my MVC3 project. The scenario is completely based on UI. It means, the users of the system have to enter the scheduling frequencies like, Defining a Job, Schedule time through the UI. I tried Quartz.Net 2.0.1. I dont have any idea that combining Quartz.Net with UI for scheduling.

Is there any possibilities to attach a scheduler with UI. Please suggest me how can i do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

there are a few open source projects which can help you.

ASP.NET MVC applications:

[Quartz.Net Admin](http://code.google.com/p/quartznet-admin/)

Pluggable:

[Quartz.Net Web Console](https://github.com/mausch/QuartzNetWebConsole)

[Crystal Quartz](https://github.com/guryanovev/CrystalQuartz) (it doesn't schedule jobs)

[Quartzmin](https://github.com/jlucansky/Quartzmin) (create and schedule jobs )

Windows Forms

[QuartzNetManager](https://github.com/adometry/QuartzNetManager)

Comment: I'm wondering if either of these projects (Crystal Quartz or Quartz.Net Web Console) support the theory of uploading *.dll plugins that you can then utilize to do scheduling.  Would be cool for corporate scenarios where you are constantly doing new projects that need to be "scheduled"

Comment: @RichardB: Have a look at this article: http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/implementing-plugin-in-quartznet-20.html

Comment: Not quite what I was thinking... unless I misunderstand... was thinking of a way where it could be done from a Web UI to the system, and loaded dynamicly into the system and utilized.

Comment: @RichardB: I don't think that's possible but I haven't investigated that much.